# How can i change javascript script into a jquery functional code

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey guys am new to jQuery,How can I change this javascript code into jQuery functional code so that I call it whenever I want at any object

LIKE: `$("#profile_img").uploader();`

Apparently this code works fine, but the problem I have is I have to populate the code every time I need to upload a file in a different file  input upload.

```
var input = document.getElementById("choosen_feeds_image"),
          formdata = false;

if (window.FormData) {
    formdata = new FormData();
    document.getElementById("feeds_upload_btn").style.display = "none";
}

if (input.addEventListener) {
    input.addEventListener("change", function (evt) {
        var i = 0, len = this.files.length, img, reader, file;

        document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = ""

        for (; i < len; i++) {
            file = this.files[i];
            if (!!file.type.match(/image.*/)) {
                if (window.FileReader) {
                    reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onloadend = function (e) {
                        showUploadedItem(e.target.result);
                    };
                    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                }
                if (formdata) {
                    formdata.append("feeds_image", file);
                }

                if (formdata) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "member/feeds_image_upload",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: formdata,
                        processData: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        success: function (res) {
                            if (res.length <= 40) {
                                document.getElementById('feeds_image_response').innerHTML = res;
                                $("#feeds_image_response").css('display', 'none');
                            } else {
                                document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = res;
                                $("#response").css('display', 'none');
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            } else {
                document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = "";
                alert("Sorry, You choose unsupported file");
            }
        }

    }), false
};
```

Comment: You can create a plugin [from stratch](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/) or [using the widget factory of jQueryUI](http://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/widget-factory/)

Comment: I wanted to convert that code into a plugin but I don't know where to start from

Comment: First of all, don't mix `document.getElementById('feeds_image_response')` with `$("#feeds_image_response")` = use either jQuery or plain js only.

Answer (score 0):

you can type all inside a function like this

```
function uploader(){
    console.log('myFuntionUploader');   
}
```

and then call the function like this

```
uploader();
```